# VC4 — GL setup not working

Tags: gui, opengles, wayland, weston

I am trying to run chromium as weston-client using ArchArm on a RPI 3+ b, but I am unable to make it use GL.

Setup:

1. Basic »AArch64« installation as described [here](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3)
2. Package Installation:

   - wayland
   - weston
   - xorg-server-xwayland
   - chromium
3. Tweaking the `/boot/config.txt` to:

.

```
#was already in
enable_uart=1

#those lines are those I have added
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
avoid_warnings=2
hdmi_drive=2
```

When launching:

```
weston --log=weston.log --no-config --xwayland --use-pixman
```

followed by opening a terminal on the desktop and running `chromium` there, te browser starts, but performance is very poor, since it does not use the GL hardware acceleration.

Running

```
weston --log=weston.log --no-config --xwayland
```

Starts a Desktop as well, but trying to chromium then, results in a frozen Desktop and only `ctrl+alt+backspace` can end that.

**I guess that there is something wrong in the overall vc4/GL setup, but I would like to know how to find the error**

```
lsmod

Module                  Size  Used by
rc_cec                 16384  0
btsdio                 20480  0
vc4                   192512  4
brcmfmac              303104  0
cec                    65536  1 vc4
brcmutil               16384  1 brcmfmac
rc_core                57344  3 rc_cec,cec
drm_kms_helper        200704  3 vc4
hci_uart              131072  0
drm                   503808  3 drm_kms_helper,vc4
joydev                 28672  0
btqca                  20480  1 hci_uart
cfg80211              729088  1 brcmfmac
btbcm                  16384  1 hci_uart
microchip              16384  1
btintel                32768  1 hci_uart
drm_panel_orientation_quirks    16384  1 drm
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
bluetooth             593920  6 btqca,btsdio,btintel,hci_uart,btbcm
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
lan78xx                61440  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
raspberrypi_hwmon      16384  0
rfkill                 32768  3 bluetooth,cfg80211
i2c_bcm2835            20480  0
pwm_bcm2835            16384  0
bcm2835_thermal        16384  0
bcm2835_wdt            16384  0
hid_multitouch         28672  0
```

.

```
ls -la /dev/dri/

total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root        100 Dec 20 01:38 .
drwxr-xr-x  18 root root       3200 Jan  2 12:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root         80 Dec 20 01:38 by-path
crw-rw----+  1 root video  226,   0 Jan  2 12:38 card0
crw-rw-rw-   1 root render 226, 128 Dec 20 01:38 renderD128
```

.

```
#log without --use-pixman
cat weston.log

Date: 2019-01-02 UTC
[13:00:58.164] weston 5.0.0
               https://wayland.freedesktop.org
               Bug reports to: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/weston/issues/
               Build: unknown (not built from git or tarball)
[13:00:58.165] Command line: weston --log=weston.log --xwayland --no-config
[13:00:58.165] OS: Linux, 4.20.0-2-ARCH, #1 SMP Fri Dec 28 19:33:32 MST 2018, aarch64
[13:00:58.165] Starting with no config file.
[13:00:58.165] Output repaint window is 7 ms maximum.
[13:00:58.165] Loading module '/usr/lib/libweston-5/drm-backend.so'
[13:00:58.178] initializing drm backend
[13:00:58.190] logind: session control granted
[13:00:58.203] using /dev/dri/card0
[13:00:58.204] DRM: supports universal planes
[13:00:58.204] DRM: supports atomic modesetting
[13:00:58.204] DRM: supports picture aspect ratio
[13:00:58.207] Loading module '/usr/lib/libweston-5/gl-renderer.so'
[13:00:58.551] EGL client extensions: EGL_EXT_device_base
               EGL_EXT_device_enumeration EGL_EXT_device_query
               EGL_EXT_platform_base EGL_KHR_client_get_all_proc_addresses
               EGL_EXT_client_extensions EGL_KHR_debug
               EGL_EXT_platform_wayland EGL_EXT_platform_x11
               EGL_MESA_platform_gbm EGL_MESA_platform_surfaceless
[13:00:58.555] warning: neither EGL_EXT_swap_buffers_with_damage or EGL_KHR_swap_buffers_with_damage is supported. Performance could be affected.
[13:00:58.555] EGL_KHR_surfaceless_context available
[13:00:58.569] EGL version: 1.4
[13:00:58.569] EGL vendor: Mesa Project
[13:00:58.569] EGL client APIs: OpenGL OpenGL_ES
[13:00:58.569] EGL extensions: EGL_ANDROID_native_fence_sync EGL_EXT_buffer_age
               EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import
               EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import_modifiers EGL_KHR_cl_event2
               EGL_KHR_config_attribs EGL_KHR_create_context
               EGL_KHR_create_context_no_error EGL_KHR_fence_sync
               EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses EGL_KHR_gl_colorspace
               EGL_KHR_gl_renderbuffer_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_2D_image
               EGL_KHR_gl_texture_3D_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_cubemap_image
               EGL_KHR_image EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_image_pixmap
               EGL_KHR_no_config_context EGL_KHR_reusable_sync
               EGL_KHR_surfaceless_context EGL_EXT_pixel_format_float
               EGL_KHR_wait_sync EGL_MESA_configless_context
               EGL_MESA_drm_image EGL_MESA_image_dma_buf_export
               EGL_WL_bind_wayland_display
[13:00:58.569] GL version: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 18.3.1
[13:00:58.569] GLSL version: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
[13:00:58.569] GL vendor: Broadcom
[13:00:58.569] GL renderer: VC4 V3D 2.1
[13:00:58.570] GL extensions: GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
               GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
               GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth24
               GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
               GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_stencil8
               GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float
               GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_depth_texture
               GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
               GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_APPLE_texture_max_level
               GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_read_format_bgra
               GL_EXT_frag_depth GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments
               GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync
               GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_EXT_unpack_subimage
               GL_NV_draw_buffers GL_NV_read_buffer GL_NV_read_depth
               GL_NV_read_depth_stencil GL_NV_read_stencil GL_EXT_draw_buffers
               GL_EXT_map_buffer_range GL_KHR_debug
               GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr
               GL_OES_required_internalformat GL_OES_surfaceless_context
               GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects
               GL_EXT_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_sub_texture
               GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp
               GL_KHR_context_flush_control GL_OES_draw_elements_base_vertex
               GL_OES_texture_border_clamp GL_KHR_no_error
               GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d
               GL_MESA_tile_raster_order
[13:00:58.570] GL ES 2 renderer features:
               read-back format: BGRA
               wl_shm sub-image to texture: yes
               EGL Wayland extension: yes
[13:00:58.603] event3  - vc4: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
[13:00:58.604] event3  - vc4: device is a pointer
[13:00:58.604] event3  - vc4: device is a keyboard
[13:00:58.619] event1  - CHICONY HP Basic USB Keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[13:00:58.619] event1  - CHICONY HP Basic USB Keyboard: device is a keyboard
[13:00:58.697] event2  - HP HP: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[13:00:58.697] event2  - HP HP: device is a pointer
[13:00:58.776] event0  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC3188-0085-04.00.00: is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen
[13:00:58.776] event0  - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC3188-0085-04.00.00: device is a touch device
[13:00:58.818] Touchscreen - eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC3188-0085-04.00.00 - /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/    0003:0EEF:C000.0001/input/input3/event0    
[13:00:58.818] input device event0 has     no enabled output associated (none named), skipping calibration for now.    
[13:00:58.844] DRM: head 'HDMI-A-1' fou    nd, connector 29 is connected, EDID make 'CND', model 'HDMI', serial '000000000000'    
[13:00:58.844] DRM: head 'Composite-1'     found, connector 44 is disconnected.    
[13:00:58.845] Registered plugin API 'w    eston_drm_output_api_v1' of size 24    
[13:00:58.845] Chosen EGL config detail    s:    
               RGBA bits: 8 8 8 0    
               swap interval rang    e: 1 - 1    
[13:00:58.847] No backlight contr    ol for output 'HDMI-A-1'    
[13:00:58.847] Output HDMI-A-1 (c    rtc 95) video modes:    
               1920x1080@60.0, pr    eferred, current, 14    8.5 MHz    
               1920x1080@60.0 16:    9, 148.5 MHz    
               1920x1080@59.9 16:    9, 148.4 MHz    
               1920x1080@60.0, 13    8.5 MHz    
               1920x1080@60.0, 74    .2 MHz    
               1920x1080@60.0 16:    9, 74.    2 MHz    
               1920x1080@59.9 16:    9, 74.    2 MHz    
               1920x1080@50.0 16:    9, 148    .5 MH    z    
               1920x1080@50.0 16:    9, 74.    2 MHz    
               1680x1050@59.9, 11    9.0 MH    z    
               1280x1024@60.0, 10    8.0 MH    z    
               1440x900@59.9, 88.    8 MHz    
               1280x960@60.0, 108    .0 MH    z    
               1366x768@59.8, 85.    5 MHz    
               1280x800@59.9, 71.    0 MHz    
               1280x720@60.0, 74.    2 MHz    
               1280x720@60.0 16:9    , 74.    2 MHz    
               1280x720@59.9 16:9    , 74.    2 MHz    
               1024x768@60.0, 65.    0 MHz    
               1440x480@60.0 16:9    , 54.    1 MHz    
               1440x480@59.9 16:9    , 54.    0 MHz    
               800x600@60.3, 40.0     MHz    
               800x600@56.2, 36.0     MHz    
               720x576@50.0 4:3,     27.0     MHz    
               720x480@60.0 4:3,     27.0     MHz    
               720x480@60.0 16:9,     27.    0 MH    z    
               720x480@59.9, 27.0     MHz    
               720x480@59.9 16:9,     27.    0 MHz    
               720x480@59.9 4:3,     27.0     MHz    
               640x480@60.0 4:3,     25.2     MHz    
               640x480@59.9, 25.2     MHz    
               640x480@59.9 4:3,     25.2     MHz    
               720x400@70.1, 28.3     MHz    
[13:00:58.848] associating input     devi    ce event3 with output HDMI-A-1 (none by udev)    
[13:00:58.848] associating input     devi    ce event1 with output HDMI-A-1 (none by udev)    
[13:00:58.848] associating input     devi    ce event2 with output HDMI-A-1 (none by udev)    
[13:00:58.848] associating input     devi    ce event0 with output HDMI-A-1 (none by udev)    
[13:00:58.849] Output 'HDMI-A-1'     enab    led with head(s) HDMI-A-1    
[13:00:58.849] Compositor capabil    itie    s:    
               arbitrary surface     rota    ti    on: yes    
               screen capture use    s y-    fl    ip: yes    
               presentation clock    : CL    OC    K_MONOT    ONIC, id 1    
               presentation clock     res    ol    ution:     0.000000001 s    
[13:00:58.850] Loading module '/u    sr/l    ib    /weston    /desktop-shel    l.so'    
[13:00:58.852] launching '/usr/li    b/we    st    on/west    on-keyboard'    
[13:00:58.856] Loading module '/u    sr/l    ib    /libwes    ton-5/xwayla    nd.so'    
[13:00:58.900] Registered plugin     API     'w    eston_x    wayland_v1'     of size 32    
[13:00:58.900] Registered plugin     API     'w    eston_x    wayland_surf    ace_v1' of     size 16    
[13:00:58.901] xserver listening     on d    is    play :0    
[13:00:58.901] launching '/usr/li    b/we    st    on/west    on-desktop-shell'    
[13:01:10.221] Spawned Xwayland s    erve    r,     pid 10    24    
[13:01:11.447] xfixes version: 5.    0    
[13:01:11.512] created wm, root 9    2    4    
[13:01:16.993] xserver exited, co    d    e 134    
[13:02:26.297] output for input d    e    vice     event3 removed    
[13:02:26.298] output for input d    e    vice     event1 removed    
[13:02:26.298] output for input d    e    vice     event2 removed    
[13:02:26.298] output for input d    e    vice     event0 removed    
[13:02:26.315] event3  - vc4: dev    i    ce re    moved    
[13:02:26.315] event1  - CHICONY     H    P Bas    ic US    B Keyboard: device removed    
[13:02:26.316] event2  - HP HP: d    e    vice     remov    ed    
[13:02:26.317] event0  - eGalax I    n    c. eG    alaxT    ou    ch EXC3188-0085-04.00.00: device removed
```

Running `glxinfo | grep render` within a weston session yields:

```
direct rendering: Yes
  GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
  GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
OpenGL renderer string: VC4 V3D 2.1
  GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, GL_OES_get_program_binary, GL_OES_mapbuffer,
```

But the `OpenGL renderer string` should be »Gallium 0.4 on VC4« if I am not mistaken?

Comment: No, that renderer string is correct.  If things are slow, I would recommend getting out your whole-system profiler (sysprof) and seeing what's going on.  A bit of info is at: https://github.com/anholt/mesa/wiki/VC4-Performance-Debugging but at a guess, your wayland clients are using shm buffers instead of dmabufs -- a common failure mode of wayland implementations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that hint, I am gonna check that out. If you follow this thread https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=230427 you can see that I could make it work by downgrading mesa on a arch arm7h install. But is it possible to set this up on Aarch64, as well, or are the failures based on the programs used, so not fixable right now?

Comment: There should be no different between aarch64 and armhf as far as the driver is concerned.